# Any to any component communication in React

Tags: reactjs, directory-structure, eventemitter

Flowchart of my project structure:

[image]

My question is about any-to-any (a2a) component communication. I have a working solution using props, but wondering what the correct way to handle Any-to-Any event handling as seen in my flowchart.

The props solution does not seem bloated, but my app is barely beyond the scale of a todo app. Which direction should I go in given the logic of my flow chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with props.  React doesn't really lend itself to "any to any communication" (for good reason).

If you find multiple components need to be notified when state changes, the answer is usually to "lift state up" to a common parent component.

Details [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).